# Hibernate inherited entities create duplicate entries

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to create data model that involves 2 entities: one entity inherits all the properties of the other.
The two entities should be saved in separate tables since they both have different purposes. I created the following hibernate structure:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS
public class Parent {
    protected String name;
    @Id
    public String getId() {
        return name;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD")
public class Child extends Parent {
    // ...
}
```

I've created a **Child** entity.
When I read all the **Parent** entities, the result contains the **Child** entry that I just created. 
It seems like creation of *Child* entity resulted in duplicate *Parent* entity, or alternatively that reading *Parent* entities return the Child entries as well.

How can I make sure that these entities saved and read separately although the inheritance relationship?

Comment: "at least this is what I see when I retrieve all Parent entities" - well, `Child` is a `Parent` so if you retrieve all parents you'll get the children as well. So check the tables themselves - there shouldn't be any 2 records with the same ids across both tables. However, your question looks like what you're actually trying to use is  `@MappedSuperclass`, i.e. a common super class for both `Parent` and `Child` that looks like an entity but isn't one (so no `@Entity`, `@Table` or `@Inheritance` there).

Comment: @Thomas With `@MappedSuperclass`, it means that `Parent` will be empty class inheriting all of it's properties from `Base` class - isn't there a way to keep only two classes? Regarding the IDs - the ID property is declared in `Parent` and used by Child as well - could it be the issue? Should I annotate another field with @id in `Child`?

Comment: No, since `Child` _extends_ `Parent` it will inherit everything and adding another id could cause other problems (such as confusing Hibernate). Generally if those 2 entities should be treated as different things (i.e. a child not being a parent) then you'll need to provide a mapping that reflects that and this means 2 separate classes - the mapped superclass is just a convenient way to reduce code duplication.